# Reset CollectorRegistry of Prometheus lib after each unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, prometheus

I have a class A that initializes a Counter in its **init**

```
from prometheus_client import Counter
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_counter = Counter('an_awesome_counter')
    def method_1(self):
        return 1
    def method_2(self):
        return 2
```

Then I write test class :

```
import unittest
import A

class ATests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = A()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.a = None
    def method_1_test(self):
        ....
    def method_2_test(self):
        ....
```

Thing is, if I run the test separately, they are fine. Yet when I run them together (Run the whole ATests class), I have the error as:

> ValueError: Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry:
>   {'an_awesome_counter'}

So it seems that the python environment isn't reset after each test run. I check the CollectorRegistry and there is a method to unregister collector, but it seems a bit ugly to do that.

I wonder if there is another way to solve this problem? Like forcing the test to run with new environment every time for example..

Thank you.

Comment: found the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488819/prometheus-client-python-how-to-assign-new-registry-without-restart

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, I moved `a = A()` out of setup(self) and turned it into a class variable as a workaround solution

Comment: Generally metrics should be module-level variables, to avoid issues such as these.

Comment: Could you edit your question so as to Add the final code that works?